# Set theory exercise involving intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $A\subseteq B$ iff $A\cap B = A$

Attempted proof - Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $x\in A\cap B$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ so $A\cap B\subseteq A$. Now, suppose $x\in A$ well then $x\in B$ by $A\subseteq B$. Since $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, $x\in A\cap B$ we then have $A\cap B = A$.

Conversely, if $A\cap B = A$ then...

I am not sure if this is right I am pretty rusty with set theory.

Comment: it is correct just it is little confusing.

Comment: @ritwiksinha ok could you make a solution that is clear as day then?

Comment: If i have to write the proof for this then i will not write the whole proof in 3 lines and write statements where they are needed, not after, not before. Although i will write the same proof as you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach to prove set inclusions and equalities is assuming that some element belongs to the first set and proving that then it belongs to the second set. For equalities, you must prove also the converse.

Let's see:

- $A\subseteq B\implies A\cap B=A$

We must prove (under the hypothesis) that $A\cap B=A$, so assume that some $x\in A\cap B$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. The former gives us directly that $A\cap B\subseteq A$. Now assume that $x\in A$. Then, the hypothesis implies that $x\in B$. Since $x$ belongs to $A$ and $B$, $x\in A\cap B$. Thus, $A=A\cap B$.

- $A\cap B=A\implies A\subseteq B$.

Can you make it?

Comment: Was my $\Rightarrow$ answer completely wrong?

Comment: I am sure you are correct but I do not understand the logic at all in your proof